# TPageControl tabs showing wrong color and style when TabPosition is tpLeft

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

First, I made a new form and made its color `clWhite`. Then, I dropped in a `TPageControl` and added 2 new pages. All was fine, the background of everything was White (in exception of inactive tab headers). But, then on the Page Control, I changed the property `TabPosition` to `tpLeft` and the tab headers changed to the default window color, while everything else remained White.

`TabPosition = tpTop`

[image: Tabs on Top]

`TabPosition = tpLeft`

[image: Tabs on Left]

Is there any way I can make it show correctly when Tabs are on the Left?

Comment: You'll need to draw them by yourself.

Comment: Why are you setting the form's color to `clWhite`? You are making an assumption about the color scheme of the end user. If the end user is using a white on black theme, you've just ignored that setting. As a general rule, you should avoid coding colors and let the system adhere to the user's preferences.

Comment: @David Please don't opinionate my question. I wouldn't have noticed it if I hadn't changed it to white.

Comment: @Jerry It's quite noticeable without changing form colour. You are transported back to Windows 2000 appearance of the tabs. And I'll not stop offering my opinions. Do feel free to ignore my advice!

Comment: @David Sorry, but I don't take advise for things like how to design my app, that's an entirely irrelevant suggestion. It's your opinion not to change it white. Has nothing to do with my issue.

Comment: @Jerry That's quite alright by me. I'll continue to offer advice and opinions and you can choose what to do with it. I'm not in the least bit offended. And yes, the advice I offered has nothing to with the question that you asked. That's why I addressed that in my answer, and offered the off topic advice in a comment.

Comment: @JerryDodge, Your comments sounds kinda rude to me. You are getting a good advice for free (even if it's not related to the Q). What's wrong with that?

Comment: "Why are you setting the form's color to clWhite? You are making an assumption about the color scheme of the end user." In fact, this is a specific request by the person who has assigned me this project. You're assuming that I am designing this myself. I'm not. Try telling this to the person who designed my task.

Comment: @Jerry You are over-reacting a touch. How could I know that detail? Plenty of people asking questions on SO get things wrong. I'm just here trying to help. If you don't need the help ignore the advice.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Don't take stuff so personally. The fact that the advice is on something that was a direct request by someone else doesn't diminish the value of that advice. Simply take that advice back to the person that made the request.

Comment: @David Sorry for overreacting, I know that makes me look like an asshole. I was having a very aggravating time yesterday, and too many people were asking me too many different questions. The last thing I wanted was irrelevant advise. I know you're not expected to know every detail of why I need to do things a certain way. I was just tipped over when you said "You're making the assumption..." when in fact you were also making an assumption.

Comment: @David I have come to the conclusion with the project leader that I'll use XE2 VCL Styles instead, because that can easily implement proper display of these tabs, and the themes can be customized by the user as well. It was based on the actual application's background which required explicit white color. The actual look-and-feel of the application were not in the requirements, but the old-fashioned style of the tabs on the left was unacceptable for this project, and I had to find a way to make it look neater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the built-in control to allow you to change this behaviour. In fact the behaviour that you are observing is the as-designed behaviour of the underlying Windows control. You can verify this readily by creating a raw Win32 `SysTabControl32` control with the [`TCS_VERTICAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760549.aspx) style. So the control already is showing correctly.

If you really wish to change the appearance, you will need to paint the tabs yourself.

Comment: As far as I remember, there was a bug when the captions were not properly displayed when the `TCS_VERTICAL` style was used and visual styles enabled. And this bug seems that MS resolved simply by disabling visual style support when the `TCS_VERTICAL` control style is used. [+1]

Comment: I'd say the same note *"This style is not supported if you use visual styles."* as for the [`TCS_RIGHT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760549(v=vs.85).aspx#TCS_RIGHT) style should have been written for `TCS_VERTICAL` as well.